# Could you kindly unblock my newbie question?

Tags: support

[I asked a question about a topic that I have to deal with even though I have no prior expertise](https://serverfault.com/questions/541993/what-h-w-components-do-i-need-to-set-up-a-colocation-rack-based-application-infr). I was not given any constructive feedback and I do firmly believe my quesstion was within the guidelines; nevertheless I have rephrased it.  Could someone please unblock it ?

Answer (score 11):

No.

Your edits have not addressed the fundamental flaws pointed out in the comments (and perhaps somewhat unkindly in TomTom's answer).

Frankly in my opinion this question is simply too basic to meet the minimum standards of "professional" imposed on Server Fault -- you should be able to determine your needs. If you cannot do so you should work with your colocation company, or *hire* a professional.

Server Fault is here to help professional system and network administrators who are "stuck" with a particularly hard problem -- we are not going to design your infrastructure for you, which is basically what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, we will help you design your infrastructure. My rate for something like this would be $200USD/h :D

Comment: @MDMarra yes, well the appropriate contact venue for that sort of thing is http://careers.stackoverflow.com -- I trust your profile there is up to date? :-D

Comment: I bid $175 an hour!

Comment: $174 from this guy!

Comment: $175 and a back massage!

Comment: $600 ... oh wait i was supposed to go down wasn't I?